# Get selected date ID (from database) in input field's value with UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, input, datepicker

I have a registration form, where people can select multiple dates selected from a database. I use the jQuery UI Datepicker. Everything works fine, but when I submit the form it saves me the date itself like this : `"09/16/2012,08/04/2011,04/19/1994"`. I would like to store the ID of the date instead.

Does anyone know how to get the ID of the selected date, and put it in the `value=""` attribute?

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="live[]" value="">

<script>
var dates = [<?php $i=0; while($dataDate = mysql_fetch_object($dates)) : echo ($i>0) ?  ", " : ""; echo '"'.date("n-j-Y", strtotime($dataDate->date)).'"'; $i++; endwhile;?>];
var enabledDays = dates;
function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,enabledDays) != -1) {
        return [true];
    }
}
return [false];
}
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
    yearRange: "1994:2012",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so heres totally new aproach to get desired outcome. 
first of all, put the dates in json obejct.

make your SQL query select id, date from database
now if you have [php json](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) available, just use

```
<?php   
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query) ) {
    $data[] = array( "id" => $row['id'], "date" => $row['date'] );
}

echo "var dates = [" . json_encode($data) . "];";
?>
```

otherwise you can do it like this:

```
<?php
echo "var dates = [";
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query) ) {
    $data[] = '{"id" : "' .$row["id"] . '", "date" : "' . $row["date"] . '" }';
}
echo implode(',', $data);
echo "];";
?>
```

Now we got json object which should look like

`[{"id" : "12", "date": "2012-02-01"},{"id" : "33", "date": "2012-02-03"}]`

i tweaked your function little bit, to work with our json object

```
function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    var datestr = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
    for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if( dates[i].date == datestr) {
            return [true];
        }
    }
    return [false];
}

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
    yearRange: "1994:2012",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Now back to getting the id

```
$('.datepciker').on('change',function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if( dates[i].date == $(this).val() )
        var index = dates[i].id;
    }

    $("#date_id_holder").val( index );

    });
```

and now your $("#date_id_holder") contains the id of selected date

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the 'dates.indexof'. Do I have to replace it with something ? Your anwser looks useful but I don't realy see where it will get each date ID.

Comment: dates is an array as in your example code, eg. 
`["2012-01-01","2012-01-04","2012-01-10"]`

what indexOf does, is similar to php array_search. It searches value of given parameter, which was $('.datepicker').val() in this case. If similar value found in array, it return index of that array. 

index is the id of selected dates key in dates array, and this is best answer i can provide with the info you have given.

If you mean something like mysql row id of selected date, please provide more information on database structure and such.

Comment: Actually I meant the ID of the mysql insert. Sorry for not having mentioning it. The mysql structure is kind of simple as each entry has a column id and date. This is the query i'm using :
  `public function getDates()
  {
   $query = "SELECT id,date FROM tour_dates ORDER BY date ASC";
   return $this->_db->SQLRequest($query);
  }`

Comment: This new approach looks very interesting ! I'm gonna test that out. Thank you for your great help man

Comment: what wouldn't i do for reputation ^^

Comment: Btw, do you know how to get the current year dynamically instead of hardcoding it in "1994:2012" ?

Comment: `var d = new Date();
var = d.getFullYear();`